# How to unit test ngOnInit in Angular to reach error block?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a code that subscribes to observable:

Product.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe({
    next: (v) => {
           this.productList = v.productData;
           },
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete() => console.info('complete')
});
}
```

product.spec.ts file is as below:

```
it('should create'), fakeAsync(() => {
component.ngOninit();
tick(1000);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(compoent).toBeTruthy();
expect(fixtiure.debugElement.query(By.css('#productTable'))).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

When I did code coverage for this, the testcode did't enter the error part of product.ts. How to write test for this part. Let me know if more information is reqiured; I am new into testing angular code.

Answer (score 0):

In your mock for `productService.getAllProducts()`, you have it return an Observable which throws an error using the `throwError` operator. That way, your unit test will hit your error handler.

Comment: I am mocking the Service using Spy like `const productServiceSpy = jasmine.CreateSpyObj<productService>(['getAllProducts']);` .  Not sure how to mock to throw an error.